magnetic boots inverted
Inverting the concept of magnetic boots -
I have a magnetic source at the "bottom" of my spacecraft. Anything that should not be attracted to it (flexible infrastructure, fragile equipment etc) is made of paramagnetic material (copper, titanium, aluminium etc.). However, to provide a consistent sense of gravity and orientation, and other reasons, my passengers wear steel-soled boots (so the bottom of the spaceship attracts them, not the other way round).
Since the magnetic source is below the floor, not the floor itself, there will not be a "clunk" and a feel of suction when placing and lifting feet on the floor.
However any other part of the body will still experience weightlessness. To overcome this, I want to line all of their (relatively tight) clothing with steel thread or pellets so that the entire body feels the same pull as gravity. (Cap/helmet for the head.)
My question is, would this work? Or does the pull of magnetism work on a different scale to gravity, so that the effect on the head will not be equivalent to the effect on the feet?

Some more problems:  Enough ferromagnetic material in clothing and a helmet to produce an illusion of gravity will be enough to create problems with people having more inertial mass than they are used to. A strong enough magnetic field for a convincing illusion of gravity will also put portable electronic equipment at risk: as it is moved, induction will create electrical currents in all its conductors. A carousel is just an easier way to fake gravity.

Why inertial mass? The magnetic pull is only "downwards".

When moving "horizontally", they'll have more inertia than they're used to. You're going to need them to wear a significant weight of steel to get an illusion of significant gravity.

"So the bottom of the spaceship attracts them, not the other way round": Unfortunately, there was this English aristocrat who lived 300 years ago, Sir Isaac Newton FRS, Master of the Mint, who decreed that if the bottom of the ship attracts the soles of the boots then the soles of the boots have to attract the bottom of the ship with an equal and opposite force. No exceptions. Bloody English aristocrats, they rule the world. ¡Viva la revolución!

I'm not conviced this is a good way to fake gravity. Ignoring the severe limitations, only your outer body would be affected, all your inner organs would still "float". Could be an even weirder feeling.

Would you take a shower wearing your iron booties in rusty (magnetic) water?

Magnetic force scales with the inverse of the cube of the distance.
This creates a major problem with your approach: tidal forces.
Gravity scales with the inverse square of the distance, and on Earth the distance between head and feet of a person adds at most a couple of meters to a distance of 6378 km (the distance where the whole Earth mass can be considered as located to compute its gravitational pull). This basically makes no difference when computing the amount of gravitational force at feet level or at head level.
On your ship, instead, adding 2 meters to a distance of few centimeters makes a large difference: if your head gets the right amount of weight, your legs will be crushed.

I see.
What if the magnetic source was dozens of metres below? or more?

@ChaniHersh: If the magnetic source is a long way off, the field gradient will be less, but the field will be a lot weaker - an inverse cube law ensures this. You'll need a ridiculously strong magnetic source to do the job.

You should also read the second answer in the link you provided, which is much better than the first.
Problem I see, with any reasonable sized magnets (like embedding a ton of small cube magnets in the floor) the force would fall of extremly rapidly.
Like your feet would stick when you place them on the ground, but lift them a centimeter and your floating again.
With a homungous magnet at the center of the ship it might kinda work (might still be possible to jump to escape velocity).

@LDutch: I think, I know what you mean now... you think about the magnetic field being so strong that it exerts the equivalent of 1G, right? Therefore it would idk require 1Tesla or so which slams the foot into the ground, ofc. You did not assume a magnet just strong enough to keep the foot on the ground, right?

Is it plausible to create the holographic image of a powerful magnet far away, visible from a certain range of angles, using weaker electromagnetic fields close by?

+1 for correctness, but you could encase the whole living capsule in a toroidal magnet to solve this problem.

The person will still have all the negative effects of weightlessness on comfort and balance, since their fluids are still weightless, it would be staggeringly expensive, prohibitively heavy, incompatible with sensitive electronics, and prone to fatal accidents. And you could get most or all of the benefit for none of the drawbacks with some elastic bands and hooks. So it's not a good solution. But it is a solution...

Also, look at pictures/video of iron filings near a magnet. They don't just stick to the magnet, they develop induced fields and stick to each other, and objects that are long and thin experience a torque aligning them with the field. Your crew would do the same, with each other and with everything intentionally or accidentally brought aboard that is magnetic.

The only way to make this idea work is to make the crew metallic androids.

This is very dangerous to do, due to the possible variance of distance to the source.
In layman's terms: magnets are weaker the further away you get. As L.Dutch explains this doesn't really matter on earth as it is such a large magnet that the difference at feet level versus head level is negligible.
However, if a magnetic source is significantly smaller, the distance starts to matter a lot. This means that to get the same effect on the head to the feet, one would need to wear only a small thread in ones shoes, but a full on juggernaut sized iron helmet on the head. This could work, if the person is standing fully upright and is extremely delicately balanced.
However, we as humans move around, bend over, sit down, etc. Meaning the heavy helmet would suddenly be closer to the magnet and experience a much larger pull, leading to disastrous results.
Therefore the approach of magnets in the floor and ferrous metal shoes could work, but I'm sure your users would prefer having the weightlessness over the danger of being ripped apart by magnetic force with a simple nod of the head.

I think I understand, that you need the Juggernaut helmet in order to increase the attraction "mass" because the magnet in the floor is acting stronger on the feet than the head? Is it really that much of a difference that sitting or standing decides about life or death? In the video you provided of the colliding magnets, I would assume that some "rubber" dampening around the sole can prevent an uncontrolled crash into the ground and breaking of the magnet in the boot.

@Antares I can't run the numbers due to lack of details, and the effect might or might not be exaggerated for dramatic effect. But the point stands that a helmet would be significantly harder to lift from the floor than from head height, depending on the size of the magnet and the distance. It would be less so if the distance was increased, but then the weight of the metal carried would need to be much more and cause all sorts of issues for lateral movement.

You mentioned a few things that can be tweaked to be (more) plausible:
(A) Forces: From a physics standpoint it does not make a difference if the boot attracts the floor or the floor attracts the boots. I can understand that you are focused on the sensations the people in boots feel when "walking". But I think the way the forces act, this would be equivalent. There is however, a difference in logic of course: If the boots are the active magnet, they could theoretically also attach to the walls or the ceiling. This might come in handy if there is work to do on the outside of the ship, but maybe unwanted in other situations.
You can consider the following:

Magnets in the floor add higher amounts of weight to the ship than equipping a few boots with magnets (maybe weight is not an issue)
Magnets in the floor have to be "always on" or there is need for some sensors and electronics to check if there is anyone at a certain spot and disable the sections if not
The boots can be fitted with sensors and software that "smartly" react to the body movements of the person. This can account for slowly/smoothly increasing attraction or loosen it again if the foot is lifted, for example.

(B) Suit: A suit is a very good idea to tackle the problem!
Basically a skintight catsuit with a cap can account for providing a sensation of "pressure" from the outside.
It will be a little different than on earth still. A pressure suit provides a pressure to the body, not a gravitational force/sensation directly. Meaning, an arm held loose would still "float" in weightlessness if not actively held down towards the body or something.
But if you want to add some special technology why the suit is able, for example, to automatically adjust magnets to simulate a sensation of gravity, that would be plausible.
The metal strings you mentioned could be part of a smart thin layer of wearable exo-"skeleton" which means, they run over all extremities, can contract and expand and therefore "control" the body to some extent. Then a really neat little AI computer interprets the body posture, predicts movements and sends appropriate commands to the suit actuators, so the person feels "as if" walking in kind-of-1G instead of 0G.
A pressure suit may not be needed, if the space craft provides air and air pressure as part of the environmental/life support systems.
There is a real world example of pressure suits. Pilots of the U-2 Spy plane were equipped with those. They were specially tailored to the pilot's body to be as tight as possible. The purpose was to provide a pressurized "hull" around the pilot, because there were no life support systems installed in the plane. But since it flew in altitudes of 21km (double the height of regular airplanes), atmosphere was so thin that a human without protective gear could not survive.
On the linked wikipedia page, you will find some pictures which might help you envisioning the suit (or a high tech version of it). It looks clunky, but towards half way down, there is one (a prototype) that looks a lot more streamlined.
Conclusion
With boots and a suit you would be able to create an environment that comes close to the conditions like on earth. But it still needs some Sci-Fi tech augmentations to be really convincing. Without such augmentations and pure magnets without controlling devices the movements would still be awkward and the feeling of weightlessness ("in the stomach") would also not be removed, if the "outer shell" is attracted to the ground (but probably this a minor issue and you can get used to it fairly quickly).

On the topic of "deadly/crushing" effects of the magnetic forces:
I suspect the question reads as the magnetic field is supposed to result in forces that are equivalent of "pulling down everything" with a force of 1G (earth-G). To obtain such a strong magnetic field, you would need to have a super strong magnet in the class of an MRT probably. And then you face the problem with the superstrong field at the ground, and a not so strong at the head. The strong magnet will accelerate the boots similar to a rail gun (if left uncontrolled), therefore exerting extreme forces on the body.
However, I thought about a magnetic field just strong enough to hold the boots on the ground, not the whole body. This would alleviate the problem of the strong forces of the magnet, but is also not capable of providing a "1G-equivalent-gravitation-effect". But it could serve for a "you can walk upright"-sort-of-movement.
It seems you have the choice between "too strong" and "maybe too weak" if employing magnetic-fields.


You probably could. As others have pointed out, the magnetic attraction will go up dramatically as the boot gets closer to the floor. But you could have a control system that reduced the boot magnetic field as you approached, so the boot does not suddenly whack onto the floor.
A more gentle system would be the velcro boots that the flight attendants wore in Kubrick's '2001' on the trip up to the space station. Those needed a slightly odd way of walking, but they could work if you moved slowly.
Neither solution is like gravity. You could have something that pulled your  top half down. There are vacuum trousers that keep the differential pressure in your bloodstream more like normal. You could have devices to simulate the weight of objects you were carrying. But you still might get acid reflux because gravity was not keeping the contents of your stomach in place like gravity does.
A better solution all round would be to rotate the spacecraft and have a very close approximation to mild gravity without any of the complications, and avoiding the health problems of prolonged weightlessness.

While most of the answers here describe the challenges with mimicking gravity with the electromagnetic force on the floor, they don't address a possible world (or in this case ship) building scenario.
Instead of making the floor magnetic, put your astronauts inside an electromagnet
Imagine the main room of your ship is round. Surrounding it are the coils of a large electromagnet from floor to ceiling. The room itself would be the core of the magnet.
Now, in the center of the electromagnet the magnet flux (which you pointed downwards) would be homogenous. In other words, you wouldn't suffer from the quickly decaying property of the static field based on distance.
With a homogeneous field you could indeed create a gravity-like feel by adding ferromagnetic material to your astronaut's gear. You just have to add the right amount to be able to simulate a consistent downward pull.
The energy requirements for this would be astronomical and the outer field would stretch far outside the room and the ship. This could double as a radiation shield much like earth's magnetosphere. Mind you, only charged particles would be deflected, emr is not charged and would therefore not be affected by the magnetic shield.
After reading through the comments, I am obliged to note that this solution was suggested by the user g s.

A homogenous field will not result in a directional force on ferromagnetic materials. You need a field gradient, or there is no potential difference from the top of the ship to the bottom, and thus no force.

A field gradient can be introduced by modifying coil windings and position relative to the floor. Ultimately, this is essentially a solenoid construction where the people are the plungers and their legs are the springs.

I don't think EM field this powerful would play nice with human bodies, nevermind ship electronics.

@GoingDurden We do this daily in MRI machines. People are largely immune to magnetic fields. Unless you have a pacemaker, that is. For electronics, you are correct. But thats for the author to solve, I'm just here to make sure the boots stick to the ground:)

@JustAnotherUser but we do not keep people inside MRI machines for months on end. Most MRI are 1T at best, and even this is medically considered unsafe for more than a regular scan, which takes minutes.  A ship sized elecromagnet that would create artificial gravity would be several times more powerful at least. It would be less like a brief MRI, more like living inside  ATLAS-preset Large Hadron Collider fro the whole trip.

@GoingDurden Space exploration is dangerous. The point here is plausibility, not safety. I mean, who wouldn't want their molecules realigned for 6 months?
